# Why is my laptop randomly turning off its keyboard?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, keyboard

so I play some valorant and a new issue has started bugging me ,I play it while charging , Mid-game the keyboard randomly dies and usb ports dont recognize an external keyboard and as soon as I remove the power cable , the laptop shuts down, When I restart  the laptop , it works fine for a while then it happens again (till now , i've only faced this problem while playing valorant so i'm thinking the issue is somehow related to that but I've been playing since the last 4 months and this started a few days back)

Comment: It seem your battery may have failed, have you checked it?

Comment: @DavidPostill hey , I have a battery report but I cant make sense of it , how would you suggest to perform a check on my battery?

Comment: Here is a similar thread discussed before, please kindly check if it was helpful to you: [Laptop keyboard turns off randomly](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/laptop-keyboard-turns-off-randomly.411105/)